# How can I quickly heal in Nier: Automata?

Tags: nier-automata

I've started playing NieR: Automata and my unfamiliarity with sword games means I constantly need to pause combat to take health items. Is there a quick-heal button on the controller that I might have missed?

Any tension from combat is evaporated once I pause time to take another restorative item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different [ways to recover your health](https://twinfinite.net/2017/02/nier-automata-restore-health-how-to/), but if you need it quickly:

> Pressing down on the d-pad will allow you to access your quick menu, where you can use a recovery item.